# How do I limit vertical JDialog resizing to a single component within the dialog?

Tags: java, swing, resize, jdialog

I have a JDialog that consists of two JPanels, one above the other. Currently, when I resize the JDialog only the bottom panel resizes in the vertical direction. However, I only want the top panel to resize. The only component that the top panel contains is a JScrollPane, so I want any vertical resizing to result in an increased/decreased view of the top panel's content. What is a good way to do this?

Thanks in advance!
elise

Comment: Please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that specifies the components and layout used.

Comment: My panels were organized using border layout, and when my mini example worked and mine didn't I realized that the top panel ascribed to the "North" constraint instead of "Center" -- after changing the constraints it now behaves as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> , I only want the top panel to resize

```
dialog.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
dialog.add(anotherPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for the proper LayoutManger. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) is a good link that explains LayoutManagers visually and does it quite well.